# Error after installing django cors header

Tags: python, django

i've installed django corsheaders from [reference](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) 
, is below my code :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'corsheaders',
'ms',
'transaksi')

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',   
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware')  

 CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL= True
```

when i run program, python manage.py runserver
and then there is an error :
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/corsheaders/checks.py", line 14, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'register'

how to solve that ?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: Django==1.8.1
django-cors-headers==1.3.1